# javac: Invalid target distribution: ${bytecode_format}

Tags: eclipse, ant, ivy

I got a project GettingStarted from [ProM-GettingStarted](https://svn.win.tue.nl/repos/prom/Packages/GettingStarted/) . I've imported it into eclipse after installing the Ivy plugin. But when I try to compile it , the console shows 'BUILD FAILED'.

- I've tried changed the jdk from 1.7 to 1.8 ,and back to 1.7 again.
- When I input 'java -version' and 'javac -version' in the 'cmd window', I can see the right infomation.
- I've copied the tools. jar from jdk/lib to jre/lib.
- I've searched for solutions, but nothing worked.

````
[echo] [build] Compiling the sources    
[javac] D:\workspace\GettingStarted\Trunk\build.xml:42: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds    
[javac] Compiling 11 source files to D:\workspace\GettingStarted\Trunk\bindist    
[javac] javac: Invalid target distribution: ${bytecode_format}    
[javac] 用法: javac <options> <source files>    
[javac] -helpBUILD FAILEDD:\workspace\GettingStarted\Trunk\build.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:D:\workspace\GettingStarted\Trunk\build.xml:42: Compile failed; 
see the compiler error output for details.  
at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)   
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:401)  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)    
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)    
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)  
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)  
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)   
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)  
at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)Caused by: D:\workspace\GettingStarted\Trunk\build.xml:42: Compile failed; 
see the compiler error output for details.  
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1150) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)  
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)  ... 15 more```

I expect to run it without error,please help me.
````

Comment: Looks like you need to pass a value for that property. Try running the command with `-Dbytecode_format=1.7`

Comment: Could you tell me more about it, please? I'm using the integrated ant plugin in eclipse.

Comment: If you're running Ant from Eclipse, there should be an "Arguments" field where you can add bytecode_format=1.7 https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-ant-running.htm

Comment: I've tried your advise ,but it still doedn't work.Oddly enough, when I delete ```source="${bytecode_format}" target="${bytecode_format}"```, it works.